# Unable to load URL: The domain of this URL is not included in the application domains - facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

i am new on this. I am trying to login with facebook and post something but when i try to do it i get an error:

Warning
Unable to load URL: The domain of this URL is not included in the application domains. In order to load this URL, add all the domains and subdomains of your application to the application domains field in your application settings.

I have downloaded SDK for php and saved it inside my root folder.

This is my index.php

```
<?php
// Include FB configuration file
require_once 'fbConfig.php';

if(isset($accessToken)){
    if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }else{
        // Put short-lived access token in session
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
        
        // OAuth 2.0 client handler helps to manage access tokens
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
        
        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;
        
        // Set default access token to be used in script
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }
    
    //FB post content
    $message = 'Test from website';
    $title = 'Post From Website';
    $link = 'http://www.algunaUrlParaRedireccionarEnElPost.com/';
    $description = 'Test';
    $picture = 'https://slp-statics.astockcdn.net/static_assets/staging/21fall/homepage/curated-asset-collection/card-2.jpg?width=580';
            
    $attachment = array(
        'message' => $message,
        'name' => $title,
        'link' => $link,
        'description' => $description,
        'picture'=>$picture,
    );
    
    try{
        // Post to Facebook
        $fb->post('/me/feed', $attachment, $accessToken);
        
        // Display post submission status
        echo 'The post was published successfully to the Facebook timeline.';
    }catch(FacebookResponseException $e){
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }catch(FacebookSDKException $e){
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
}else{
    // Get Facebook login URL
    $fbLoginURL = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectURL, $fbPermissions);
    
    // Redirect to Facebook login page
    echo '<a href="'.$fbLoginURL.'"><img src="fb-btn.png" /></a>';
}
```

Also i get this file for sdk configuration(config.php)

```
<?php
if(!session_id()){
    session_start();
}

// Include the autoloader provided in the SDK
require_once __DIR__ . '/php-graph-sdk-5.x/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

// Include required libraries
use Facebook\Facebook;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;

/*
 * Configuration and setup Facebook SDK
 */
$appId         = 'algunID'; //Facebook App ID
$appSecret     = 'algunaAppSecret'; //Facebook App Secret
$redirectURL   = 'http://localhost:8077/fbPost/'; //Callback URL
$fbPermissions = array('publish_actions'); //Facebook permission

$fb = new Facebook(array(
    'app_id' => $appId,
    'app_secret' => $appSecret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
));

// Get redirect login helper
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

// Try to get access token
try {
    if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){
        $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
    }else{
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }
} catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
     echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
} catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
}
?>
```

I looked for a solution but everyone fixed this error adding their domain url inside their app created on facebook developers but i can't because i am running this on localhost

Comment: You have to whitelist the domain in your facebook app

Comment: but im working on localhost and its not allowed

Comment: Go to your app `Settings` -> `Advanced` -> `Share Redirect Allow List` -> add `localhost` or Check `Allow Cross Domain Share Redirects`

Answer (score 0):

```
Facebook Login -> Settings -> Valid OAuth redirect URIs
```

You should also have it in mind that [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) is not the same as example.com. Add both formats to the redirect URL.

The login with Facebook button on your site is linking to:

https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?client_id=1500708243571026&redirect_uri=http://openstrategynetwork.com/_oauth/facebook&display=popup&scope=email&state=eyJsb2dpblN0eWxlIjoicG9wdXAiLCJjcmVkZW50aWFsVG9rZW4iOiIwSXhEU05XamJjU0VaQWdqcmF6SXdOUWRuRFozXzc0X19lbVhGWUJTZGNYIiwiaXNDb3Jkb3ZhIjpmYWxzZX0=

Notice: redirect_uri=http://openstrategynetwork.com/_oauth/facebook

If you instead change the link to:

redirect_uri=http://openstrategynetwork.com/_oauth/facebook?close

It should work. Or, you can change the Facebook link to http://openstrategynetwork.com/_oauth/facebook

You can also add http://localhost/_oauth/facebook to the valid redirect URIs.

Facebook requires that you whitelist redirect URIs, since otherwise people could login with Facebook for your service, and then send their access token to an attacker's server! And you don't want that to happen ;]

Comment: where should i change `redirect_uri=http://openstrategynetwork.com/_oauth/facebook?close`  ? i changed it in config.php `$fbPermissions = array('publish_actions'); `  to `$fbPermissions = array('redirect_uri=http://openstrategynetwork.com/_oauth/facebook?close'); ` but i get another error. Sorry im new with this

Comment: Also tried to add localhost to redirect URI but localhost is not allowed to be added.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your app `Settings` -> `Advanced` -> `Share Redirect Allow List` -> add `localhost` or `Check Allow Cross Domain Share Redirects`

[image]

Comment: I added `localhost,localhost:8077,localhost:8077/fbPost`  to share redirect allow list but still not working. Also under basic Settings added a platform `(http://localhost:8077/)` . Do you think there's soemthing wrong with my code?